# target="_blank" Firing Two Requests

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

The following HTML is sending two requests to my REST WebService:

```
<a href="/pathto/web/service/3201329" target="_blank">
  <img class="downloadImg" src="static/images/download_icon.png">
</a>
```

If I remove the 'target="_blank"' bit, it will only send one request to my WebService.  I noticed the same behavior when attempting a work-around with JavaScript:

```
onclick="window.open(this.href)"
```

Any ideas why this could be occurring?  Thank you for your help!

**UPDATE:**  There was a user error on my end.  In a previous iteration, I'd added a click handler to the image.  I'm not sure why I duplicated the effort with the HREF, but that's what the issue is.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Where do the requests to the REST service come into play? Can you post that code please?

Comment: Do you have other JavaScript tied to your links or images?

Comment: I have no other JS tied to my links or images.

Comment: Scratch that last response...  :-(

Answer (score 1):

I can't see that happening in the first scenario since it's just an ordinary link.

I can possibly see it happening in the second.  The onclick event opens a new window using the url.  It returns execution back to the browser, then the standard navigation for the  tag takes over and goes to the page as well.

Try:

```
onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;"
```

As an aside, using inline javascript nowadays is somewhat frowned upon.  The way to do it now is to add a click handler when the document loads.  That's really outside of the scope of this question though....

Comment: That's my thought too. He's not stopping the return from the js that triggers the open, so the click propagates back to the anchor.

Comment: I tried replacing the target/blank HTML with the JavaScript you posted above.  It functions exactly the same in that it opens the link in a new tab (Chrome), and it sends two requests to the server.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use target="_blank", if you want to do it the javascript way. You can call a script before the anchor tag like this:

```
<script>
    function popup(url) {
    alert (url);
        newwindow= window.open(url);
        if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
        return false;
      }
</script>
```

and then the anchor tag like this:

```
<a href="" onclick="return popup('http://www.example.com')"></a>
```

Comment: But wouldn't this get blocked by popup blockers most of the time?

Comment: When I mentioned the JS solution, I meant that I replaced the "target/blank" with the JS, and it still fired two requests to my WebService.  I didn't use them in conjunction.

Comment: My bad then. Can you show us a bit more of the code? I don't think the anchor tag itself would act like that.